# Why is Ubuntu getting rid of the Unity Environment?

Tags: unity, gnome

I have recently been reading that the next LTS version of Ubuntu will be using the Gnome desktop environment and not the unity one.

I am curious as to why they are stoping the unity desktop as it is very nice and user friendly and feels more natural (in my opinion) than the Gnome environment.

Comment: FWIW - In theory Gnome can be configured to look and feel like unity, or very close, it would just be a gnome theme. I suppose it depends on user interest, but my advice would be to write a theme if you do not care for the new ubuntu default whatever that is.

Comment: The GNOME desktop which will be shipped in Ubuntu will likely be quite similar to Unity. See the relevant articles on [OMG! Ubuntu](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/), for example, "[The New Ubuntu Dock](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/new-ubuntu-dock-first-look)", "[Ubuntu Sees Sense, Will Support Indicator Applets in Ubuntu 17.10](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/08/ubuntu-sees-sense-will-support-indicator-applets-ubuntu-17-10)" and so on. Basically, Canonical got tired of supporting their one-of-a-kind desktop and found that is was easier to customize GNOME.